# Cin expression with assignmnet operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn c++ and I got struck while using `cin` in my code

`int input;
vec.push_back(cin>>input);`

or

`int input;
sum+=cin>>input`

can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Neither.

Calling `cin>>input` is the same as calling `cin.operator>>(input)`.

The function declaration looks somewhat like this:`std::istream& operator>>(int& val)`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't works is that you can't assign an istream& to an integer.

To put it simply, operators in c++ works like functions. They get a parameter, which stands of the right side and give you a return value, which stands on the left side of the operator and represents the expression.

The Operator ">>" returns an istream reference. You want to assign this istream reference to an integer and this isn't possible. 
The overloaded operator to get an integer is

```
std::istream& operator>>(int& val)
```

This means that the value you want to assign with this operator must be the parameter.

```
int input;
std::cin >> input;
sum += input;
```

You can have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) to see the documentation of operator >> in istream.

And you can have another look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) to see how overloading in c++ works.

And there are many other tutorials to this topic.

Google is your friend ;)